# Concatenate C# strings to JavaScript/knockout functions/observables

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

I am trying something like this:

```
string temp = "";

<script type="text/javascript">
if (@min >= @customDataBindArray+'().length') {
    for ( i = 0; i < @columns.Count; i++)
    {
        @temp+="<td>&nbsp;</td>";
    }

    for (i = 0; i < @min - @customDataBindArray+'().length'); i++)
    {
        $('.List tr:last').after(@Html.Raw("<tr>" + @temp + "</tr>"));
    }
}
</script>
```

I see some problems here

1. I get a `System.NullReferenceException` for `@temp`, but I set it to an empty string,removing `@Html.Raw` will remove the exception, after removing `@Html.Raw` -> `@temp` is not written to the final html-file
2. I am trying to concatenate an observable `@customDataBindArray+'().length`, this will result in `MyObservable+'().length'`

Maybe you can give me a helping hand?

Comment: Your confusing client-side and server-side code.  Don't do that.

Comment: I would suggest not using C#/Razor to generate JavaScript. Instead, send your data to the page with ajax and generate the observables from that data.

Comment: you cannot assign data back to ViewModel Object from JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

you cannot assign data back to ViewModel Object from JavaScript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
var temp = '';
    if (@min >= @customDataBindArray+'().length') {
        for ( i = 0; i < @columns.Count; i++)
        {
            temp+="<td>&nbsp;</td>";
        }

        for (i = 0; i < @min - @customDataBindArray+'().length'); i++)
        {
            $('.List tr:last').after("<tr>" + temp + "</tr>");
        }
    }
    </script>
```

this might work

Comment: Using `@customDataBindArray+'().length'` will result in `MyObservable+'().length'`

Comment: the best this to do it to store the values in hidden @html tags and use dosumentread and read it from jquery and use the values in the function. otherwise it is going to be very dirty and bad programming

Comment: May be there is a method like `@Html.Raw(...)`, which can concatenate that string so that it will look a normal variable ?